# How to fix blog article view and share #'s?

Tags: plugins, themes, front-end, blog, views

This is about public views on the front-end of our blog.

All newly published articles view counter & share #'s have stopped updating.

So, if someone views the article or shares it on social media, the #'s do not update, it still says zero views, zero shares.

We're using the Newspaper theme.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you (or your hosting company) use any caching solutions?

Comment: Hi Krzysiek, we use WP Super Rocket right now. Would you recommend using a different one?

Answer (score 0):

The Newspaper theme uses ajax to display views and pull in social data.

https://forum.tagdiv.com/ajax-view-count/

In order to keep requests to admin-ajax.php to a minimum, you should reduce the number of different blocks used on your site as well as reduce the ajax filters and pagination for each block. This will reduce server requests considerably.

Please clear the cache of your theme or turn off the caching plugin (WP Super Cache is recommended by theme author)

Can you please check if there are any PHP errors in your web server’s error.log or wordpress logs

You should also use the Inspect option in your browser to see if any errors are highlighted.

The theme offers an official support forum at http://forum.tagdiv.com/forum/newspaper/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond! We will test that out. Do you do paid Wordpress work? If so, please message me. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I do, can't message on here, but you can click my picture and get my website from my profile